# Does Aptana 3 recognize CSS3?

Tags: css, aptana

While learning CSS3 I realized that Aptana Studio 3 doesn´t recognize CSS3 source. I have updated the latest features for the IDE but it is still trying to use CSS2. I get this error for CSS3 background statement:

```
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);

ValueError: background (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background) Too many values or values are not recognized.
```

Do I have to install a particular plugin for Aptana??

**Edited**

Jul 26th 2011, the bug is still there after automatic update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aptana correctly recognises CSS statements after updating it to the latest version.
Ensure you have the latest version.

Comment: Absolutely right! On a sidenote, I had auto-update enabled, but if you don't run Aptana as admin on windows 7, it doesn't update. First I was baffled with your answer, because I assumed aptana was up to date, but looking into it, I had to update while running aptana as admin, to finally also get better css markup support.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that the CSS validator that's included (which comes from the W3C) is not very good about CSS 3. There are plans to replace that, but in the mean time, the easiest thing to do is to either filter the particular warning, or to disable it altogether.

To do so, go to Preferences > Studio > Validation and choose CSS. There you can disable the validation, or add a filter of something like ".*Too many values or values are not recognized.*"

More information: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Adding+custom+error+message+filters+to+the+Problems+View

Comment: Thank you! but I cannot mark this answer as the correct one cause it isn't a solution, it is just a way to avoid the error message.

Comment: Sure. However, unless someone implements a validator for CSS3 inside Studio other than the current one, it's the only option, other than filing a bug.