# Aptana Studio 3 CSS3 validation support

Tags: css, aptana

Just can't find any information clearly. Does Aptana Studio 3 support CSS3 validation?

Is it possible to get full CSS3 validation and to get rid of the messages like "transparent is not a color value"? No! Don't propose the filters workaround. What the point of such validation is then?

I've read that Aptana internally is using W3C validation tool. But W3C is already released an online CSS3 validation tool. I have the latest Aptana build of 3.4.0.201304151603 version number, and can't figure is there a possibility to turn on CSS3 validation, or is it absent in Aptana at all?

Comment: Take a look at this post [Does Aptana 3 recognize CSS3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716933/does-aptana-3-recognize-css3)

Comment: @Flowen Already. But I have the latest version and still it validate as CSS2 or CSS2.1 Maybe there is some option somewhere in properties or preferences?

Comment: I dont know if that option exists, look at ` Window -> Preferences -> Aptana Studio -> Validation`

Comment: @Flowen No, couldn't found anything there. Even couldn't found clearly stated by Aptana level of CSS validation support. Is it 2 or 2.1? Where to look for this kind of information?

Comment: Just saw this post [Aptana Studio 3 CSS Recognizing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716933/does-aptana-3-recognize-css3) "unless someone implements a validator for CSS3 inside Studio other than the current one..."

Comment: @Flowen It's the post from August of 2011. Now it is May of 2013. Two years and still no CSS3 support? BTW. There is always a phrase of Ingo Muschenetz: "The problem is that the CSS validator that's included (which comes from the W3C) is not very good about CSS 3". Don't know how it was in 2011, but W3C's validator validate CSS3 pretty well now: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input